# When is the copy constructor called for this struct?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do some test with {}-lists. When I compiled this in VS2015, the output is

> ```
> copy A 0
> ```

Just don't get it, where is copy constructor called ?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(int i) : m_i(i) {}
    A(const A& a)
    {
        std::cout << "copy A " << m_i << std::endl;
    }
    int m_i = 0;
};

struct B
{
    B(const A& a) : m_a(a) {}
    B(const A& a1, const A& a2) {}
    A m_a;
};

int main()
{
    A a1{1}, a2{2};
    B b({ a1, a2 });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get [no output](http://ideone.com/JpwCdM).

Comment: @zenith compile with `-fno-elide-constructors` if using g++/clang++

Comment: `B b({a1, a2});` is almost equivalent to `B b(B{a1, a2});` The copy probably happens from the `B{a1, a2}.m_a` temporary to `b.m_a`

Comment: @dyp That's probably right - that seems like correct behavior too. Shouldn't don't gcc/clang pick up that constructor?

Comment: @dyp That's exactly what happens, you should post an answer.

Comment: @Barry, I just tried with Clang and it does if you tell it not to elide the copy.

Comment: Can see the behaviour [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fQNw6740ZxZSAPGw)

Comment: Compiling it in g++, i came across a few compilations errors, after correcting those, i didn't saw any o/p

Comment: g++ with the `-fno-elide-constructors` option produces the output just like VS seemed to normally.

Comment: @Barry This is just copy elision. Same as `B b = B{a1, a2};`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short version:

In a direct-initialization like `B b({a1, a2})`, the *braced-init-list* `{a1, a2}` is considered as *one* argument to a constructor of `B`. This argument `{a1, a2}` will be used to initialize the first parameter of the constructor. `B` contains an implicitly-declared constructor `B(B const&)`. A reference `B const&` can be initialized from `{a1, a2}` by creating a *temporary `B`*. This temporary contains an `A` subobject, and this subobject will finally be copied to `b.m_a` via the `B(B const&)` copy constructor.

Compare to:

```
void foo(B const& b0);
foo({a1, a2}); // one argument, creates a temporary `B`
```

We won't see any copying for initializations of the form `B b{a1, a2}` nor `B b(a1, a2)` nor `B b = {a1, a2}`, because those cases consider `a1` and `a2` as the (separate) arguments  - unless a viable `std::initializer_list` constructor exists.

---

Long version:

The class `B` contains the following constructors:

```
B(const A& a) : m_a(a) {}                      // #0
B(const A& a1, const A& a2) {}                 // #1
B(B const&) = default; // implicitly declared     #2
B(B&&) = default;      // implicitly declared     #3
```

`#3` will not be present in VS2013, due to a lack of support of implicitly-provided special move functions. #0 is not used in the OP's program.

The initialization `B b({a1, a2})` has to select one of those constructors. We supply only one argument `{a1, a2}`, so #1 is not viable. #0 isn't viable either, since `A` cannot be constructed from two arguments. Both #2 and #3 are still viable (#3 doesn't exist in VS2013).

Now, overload resolution tries to initialize a `B const&` or a `B&&` from `{a1, a2}`. A temporary `B` will be created and bound to this reference. Overload resolution will prefer #3 to #2, if #3 exists.

The creation of the temporary again looks at the four constructors shown above, but now we have *two* arguments `a1` and `a2` (or an `initializer_list`, but that's irrelevant here). #1 is the only viable overload, and the temporary is created via `B(const A& a1, const A& a2)`.

So, we essentially end up with essentially `B b( B{a1, a2} )`. The copy (or move) from the temporary `B{a1, a2}` to `b` can be *elided* (copy-elision). This is why g++ and clang++ don't call the copy ctor nor the move ctor of neither `B` nor `A`.

VS2013 seems not to elide the copy-construction here, and it cannot move-construct since it cannot implicitly provide #3 (VS2015 will fix that). Therefore, VS2013 calls `B(B const&)`, which copies `B{a1, a2}.m_a` to `b.m_a`. This calls `A`'s copy constructor.

If #3 exists, and the move is not elided, the implicitly-declared move constructor #3 is called. Since `A` has an explicitly-declared copy constructor, no move constructor will be implicitly declared for `A`. This also leads to a copy construction from `B{a1, a2}.m_a` to `b.m_a`, but via the move ctor of `B`.

---

In VS2013, if we manually add a move ctor to `A` and to `B`, we'll notice that `A` will be moved instead of copied:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(int i) : m_i(i) {}
    A(const A& a)
    {
        std::cout << "copy A " << m_i << std::endl;
    }
    A(A&& a)
    {
        std::cout << "move A " << m_i << std::endl;
    }
    int m_i = 0;
};

struct B
{
    //B(const A& a) : m_a(a) {}
    B(const A& a1, const A& a2) {}
    B(B const&) = default;
    B(B&& b) : m_a(std::move(b.m_a)) {}
    A m_a;
};
```

It is typically easier to understand such programs by tracing from *every* constructor. Using the MSVC-specific `__FUNCSIG__` (g++/clang++ can use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`):

```
#include <iostream>

#define PRINT_FUNCSIG() { std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << "\n"; }

struct A
{
    A() PRINT_FUNCSIG()
    A(int i) : m_i(i) PRINT_FUNCSIG()
    A(const A& a) : m_i(a.m_i) PRINT_FUNCSIG()
    int m_i = 0;
};

struct B
{
    B(const A& a1, const A& a2) PRINT_FUNCSIG()
    B(B const& b) : m_a(b.m_a) PRINT_FUNCSIG()
    A m_a;
};

int main()
{
    A a1{1}, a2{2};
    B b({ a1, a2 });
    return 0;
}
```

This prints (w/o the comments):

```
__thiscall A::A(int)  // a1{1}
__thiscall A::A(int)  // a2{2}
__thiscall A::A(void) // B{a1, a2}.m_a, default-constructed
__thiscall B::B(const struct A &,const struct A &) // B{a1, a2}
__thiscall A::A(const struct A &) // b.m_a(B{a1, a2}.m_a)
__thiscall B::B(const struct B &) // b(B{a1, a2})
```

---

Additional factoids:

- Both VS2015 and VS2013 **do** elide the copy construction of `B b(B{a1, a2});` but not the original `B b({a1, a2})`.

Comment: And you see the copy ctor of `A` invoked by the implicit move ctor of `B` since the move constructor of `A` is deleted because explicit copy operations disable implicit moves.

Comment: @vsoftco In VS2013, neither `B` nor `A` won't have a move ctor. But you're right wrt the Standard.